# Building regression using Categorical features

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to use house price prediction as a practical example to learn machine learning. Currently I ran into the problem regarding to neighborhood.

With most machine learning examples, I saw features such as number of bedrooms, floor spaces, land area are used. Intuitively, these features has strong correlations to house prices. However, this is not the case for neighborhood. Let's say I randomly assign a neighborhood_id to each neighborhood.  I won't be able to tell neighborhood with id 100 has higher or lower house price than neighborhood with id 53.

I am wondering if I need to do some data pre-processing, such as find the average price for each neighborhood then use the processed data, or there are existing machine learning algorithm that figure out the relation from seemingly unrelated feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to interpret the relationship between neighborhood and housing price in a regression model with continuous and categorical data. From what I remember, R handles categorical variables automatically using one-hot encoding.

There are ways to approach this problem by creating data abstractions from categorical variables:

#### 1) One-Hot Encoding

Let's say you're trying to predict housing prices from floor space and neighborhood. Assume that floor space is continuous and neighborhood is categorical with 3 possible neighborhoods, being A, B and C. One possibility is to encode neighborhood as a one-hot vector and treat each categorical variables as a new binary variable:

```
neighborhood A B C
     A       1 0 0
     B       0 1 0 
     B       0 1 0
     C       0 0 1
```

The regression model would be something like:

```
y = c0*bias + c1*floor_space + c2*A + c3*B + c4*C
```

Note that this neighborhood variable is similar to bias in regression models. The coefficient for each neighborhood can be interpreted as the "bias" of the neighborhood.

## 2) From categorical to continuous

Let's call Dx and Dy the horizontal and vertical distances from all neighborhoods to a fixed point on the map. By doing this, you create a data abstraction that transforms neighborhood, a categorical variable, into two continuous variables. By doing this, you can correlate housing prices to horizontal and vertical distance from your fixed point.

Note that this is only appropriate when the transformation from categorical to continuous makes sense.